# What is the difference between RSTUDIO_USER_IDENTITY and USER environment variables in RStudio?

Tags: rstudio, rstudio-server

Sys.getenv returns RSTUDIO_USER_IDENTITY and USER environment variables. Does anyone have an explanation of what these environment variables do?

Comment: I should also mention that I am running RStudio in server mode accessing it through a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

`USER` is a system environment variable unrelated to RStudio. It's what you should use to pick up the current system username (i.e the username of the user running the R session).

`RSTUDIO_USER_IDENTITY` is generally the same as `USER`, though it can differ in debug configurations. You probably want to use `USER` unless you have a very specific reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you use RStudio desktop, the user name is returned with `Sys.getenv("USER")`; if you use RStudio Server (through a browser), the user name is returned with `Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_USER_IDENTITY")`.